# returning object that returns functions

Tags: javascript, object, functional-programming

I need to write a function in JavaScript that takes a number and returns an object that returns chainable functions (without using OOP).

Example:

```
func(3).not().not().equals(4)
```

would outputs `false`.

And:

```
func(5).equals(5)
```

would output: `true`

This is the code I have written:

```
const func = (obj) => { 
  const obj2 = {
    not: () => {
      return !obj
    },
    equals: (num) => {
     return obj === num
   }
 }
  return obj2 
}
```

It works when I call `func(3).not()` or `func(5).equals(5)`, but doesn't allow me to chain the functions so calling `func(5).not().equals(5)` returns an error saying that this is not a function.

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: Why *would* that work? not and equals return booleans, which don't have the equals or not properties. If they returned instances themselves, you'd have to provide a method to get the result out, too.

Comment: `.not()` needs to return an object. It would be easier if you coded this using a class.

Comment: "*without using OOP*" - that makes no sense. Having objects with methods **is** OOP.

Comment: _"I need to write ...."_ I doubt you **need to** write your code like that. You **want to** write your code like that, but it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a closure to store both the initial input and the state of the operation:

```js
const func = (input) => {
  let not = false
  const obj = {
    not: () => {
      not = !not
      return obj
    },
    equals: (num) => {
      return not ? input !== num : input === num
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(func(5).not().equals(5))
console.log(func(5).not().not().equals(5))
console.log(func(5).not().equals(4))
console.log(func(5).not().not().equals(4))
```

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: I find it always fascinating how much closures look like the private state of objects (and vice-versa, depends where you're looking from, of course).

Answer (score 1):

That's a very weird way to compose functions. Let's think about what's actually happening.

```js
func(3).not().not().equals(4)

// is equivalent to

not(not(equals(4)(3)))

// where

const not = x => !x;

const equals = x => y => x === y;
```

The simplest way to implement this chain would be as follows.

```js
const equals = x => toBool(y => x === y);

const toBool = func => ({
    not: () => toBool(x => !func(x)),
    func
});

const example1 = equals(4).not().not().func(3);
const example2 = equals(5).func(5);

console.log(example1); // false
console.log(example2); // true
```

However, this is a forward chain. You want a backward chain. Unfortunately, there's a problem.

1. In a forward chain `.func(x)` marks the end of the chain.
2. In a backward chain `.equals(x)` marks the end of the chain.

This means that in a backward chain, you wouldn't be able to write the following expression.

```js
func(3).not().not().equals(4).add(1)

// expected to be equivalent to

not(not(equals(4)(add(1)(3))))

// but actually equivalent to

not(not(equals(4)(3))).add(1)

// which evaluates to

false.add(1)
```

On the other hand, you would be able to do this quite easily using a forward chain.

```js
const id = x => x;

const toNum = func => ({
    add: x => toNum(y => x + func(y)),
    equals: x => toBool(y => x === func(y)),
    func
});

const toBool = func => ({
    not: () => toBool(x => !func(x)),
    func
});

const { add, equals } = toNum(id);

const example1 = equals(4).not().not().func(3);
const example2 = add(1).equals(4).not().not().func(3);

console.log(example1); // false
console.log(example2); // true
```

By the way, this is an object-oriented design pattern even though it doesn't make use of classes.

My advice would be to write plain old functions.

```js
const add = (x, y) => x + y;

const equals = (x, y) => x === y;

const not = x => !x;

const example1 = not(not(equals(4, 3)));
const example2 = not(not(equals(4, add(1, 3))));

console.log(example1); // false
console.log(example2); // true
```

The simplest solutions are usually the best. Source: [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).

Answer (score 1):

To return another object with the same methods that wraps the new value, simply call `func` again:

```js
const func = (obj) => { 
  const obj2 = {
    not: () => {
      return func(!obj)
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    },
    equals: (num) => {
      return obj === num
    }
  }
  return obj2 
}
console.log(func(3).not().not().equals(4))
console.log(func(5).equals(5))
console.log(func(3).not())
```

Comment: That doesn't do what you expect it to do. For example, consider the expression `func(3).not().not().equals(3)` which should return `true` but instead returns `false`.

Comment: The expression `func(3).not().not().equals(3)` should evaluate to `!!(3 === 3)` but in your example it evaluates to `3 === !!3`.

Comment: @AaditMShah `!!3` is `true`, which is not equal to `3`, so from my perspective that's expected. The OP didn't give this particular example, so we're not sure which one he meant. I do like your answer as well, though :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what the OP is trying to do. XD

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object for return as interface and store value and negation.

```js
var object = {
        func: function (value) {
            object.left = value;
            return object;
        },
        not: function() {
            object.negation = !object.negation;
            return object;
        },
        equals: function (value) {
            var result = value === object.value;
            return object.negation ? !result : result;
        }
    },
    func = object.func;


console.log(func(3).not().not().equals(4));
```